# Animating search bar

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, uisearchbar

I want to do something similar to the search bar in the IOS 10 Music app.
How might I do this? Here are some pictures:

[image: Start]

[image: End]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to implement Search bar with scope? Please elaborate.

Sample :

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setScopeButtonTitles:@["Apple Music",@"Your Library"]];
```

Check below properties in File Inspector:

- Capabilities - Show Cancel Button
- Capabilities - Show Scope Bar